# form validation before calling an onclick method in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, validation, jsp

I added html validation and need to all a js method on button click. here the onclick method fires even the fields are not filled.. (it shows the alert that fields are required but executes the on click method too )

```
  <form >
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="to" placeholder = "directed to: Admin" required>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="header" placeholder = "message heading" required>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="content" rows="3" placeholder = "message body" required></textarea>
    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-warning" onclick="saveMessage()" >Search</button></form>
```

js function

```
 function saveMessage(){
    var to = document.getElementById('to').value;
             var header = document.getElementById('header').value;
             var body = document.getElementById('content').value;
             var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xhttp.onreadystatechange= function(){
                 if(xhttp.readyState===4 & xhttp.status===200){
                    swal("Success!", "Submitted the message successfully!", "success");

                 }
             };
             xhttp.open("POST","addCusMessage?valto="+to+"&valheader="+header+"&valbody="+body,true);
             xhttp.send();
         } 

  </script>
```

Comment: Can you share the code of the saveMessage() function?

Comment: added above.. its to pass the input fields to another servelet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields with the "required" attribute must be filled in with value before **submission of a form**.

You are not submitting the form: you are reading the values of the fields  and use these values to build your XMLHttpRequest.

You should test the values of the fields in your saveMessage() function, like (example only for the header field)

```
if(header == "") {
    alert("Header cannot be empty");
} else {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange= function(){
         if(xhttp.readyState===4 & xhttp.status===200){
                swal("Success!", "Submitted the message successfully!", "success");

             }
         };
     xhttp.open("POST","addCusMessage?valto="+to+"&valheader="+header+"&valbody="+body,true);
      xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added a validation to the js function and it solved the issue. Thank you